# Error in running Pyomo with CBC solver on Docker

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, pyomo, coin-or-cbc

I am trying to run a python application using `pyomo` with `cbc` solver.

When I run it in a docker container it is giving the following error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'polynomial_degree'

I am inclined to believe that it is linked with Python not being able to find the `cbc` executable.

Here is my `Dockerfile` file:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    gcc \
    libglpk-dev \
    glpk-utils \
    curl \
    git \
    software-properties-common \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN python3 -m venv venv \
    && . venv/bin/activate \
    && python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip3 install -r requirements.txt

RUN /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)" \
    && (echo; echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"') >> /root/.profile \
    && eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)" \
    && brew install glpk \
    && brew install ipopt \
    && brew install cbc

ENV PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/cbc/bin:$PATH"
ENV LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/cbc/lib"
ENV CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/cbc/include"
ENV PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/cbc/lib/pkgconfig"

ENV PATH="${PATH}:/app/venv/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/usr/local/opt/cbc/bin"

EXPOSE 8501

HEALTHCHECK CMD curl --fail http://localhost:8501/_stcore/health

ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run", "app.py", "--server.port=8501", "--server.address=0.0.0.0"]
```

And here is the `requirements.txt` file:

```
numpy==1.24.3
pandas==2.0.2
pyomo==6.6.1
streamlit==1.23.1
streamlit-aggrid==0.3.4.post3
```

Please let me know how to resolve this.

I have tried executing `which cbc` from the python code and it finds the executable to `cbc`

Comment: I am betting there is a problem with your model.  The error implies recognition of the `numpy` object.  What happens when you run the **exact same** pyomo file with the same data outside of Docker-land?  Also, you might want to work on this question to make it reproducible....  boil down your pyomo code and data to something small which produces the error and add it to the post for better t/s.

Comment: It is working outside but not inside the docker. @AirSquid

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this myself.

Notably, there are two things that fixed it, the first being that the virtual environment directory needs to be added at the start of the `PATH` environment variable instead of at the end of it:

```
ENV PATH="/app/venv/bin:${PATH}"
```

Secondly, the `altair` package was needed in the `requirements.txt` file along with some changes to the versions of the existing packages.

Here is the fixed `requirements.txt` file:

```
Pyomo==6.5.0
streamlit==1.18.1
streamlit-aggrid==0.3.4.post3
altair==4.2.2
```

The `LDFLAGS`, `CPPFLAGS` and `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variables don't need to be set in the `Dockerfile`.

Also, symbolic links to `cbc`, `ipopt` and `glpsol` are created by `homebrew` inside the directory `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin`, so we need to add that directory to the path.

```
ENV PATH="$PATH:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin"
```

Here is the fixed `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN python -m venv venv

ENV PATH="/app/venv/bin:${PATH}"

RUN . venv/bin/activate \
    && python -m pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install curl git gcc \
    && /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)" \
    && (echo; echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"') >> /root/.profile \
    && eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)" \
    && brew install glpk \
    && brew install ipopt \
    && brew install cbc

ENV PATH="$PATH:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin"

EXPOSE 8501

HEALTHCHECK CMD curl --fail http://localhost:8501/_stcore/health

ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run", "app.py", "--server.port=8501", "--server.address=0.0.0.0"]
```